# sql server scan only last week records from Table using stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

i am working on sql server 2008..i have a Transaction_tbl ,that contains more than 2 lack data..each day increasing 30000 records..i have a stored procedure..that need to fetch only last 7 days transaction from this table..but while executing stored procedure that scanning all table and giving result..that make my system slow..so i dont want to scan all table..
    **i want to scan only last 7 days records from table and give the proper data..**
my Table structure like this:

```
transactID   int
TBarcode     varchar(20)
Locid         int
PlateNo       varchar(20)
dtime         datetime
DelEcode     nvarchar(50)
Paydate     datetime
KeyRoomDate  datetime
DelDate      datetime
Status      int
```

my stored procedure like this:

```
 ALTER procedure [dbo].[IBSFVRIPodiumG]
       @locid INTEGER = NULL
    AS BEGIN
       SET NOCOUNT ON

       DECLARE @TodayMinus7Days DATETIME
    Declare @krrt integer
    Declare @DT integer
       SET @TodayMinus7Days = getdate()-7

       SELECT  
           t.TBarcode, t.PlateNo, t.DelEcode,cast(t.Paydate as Time) [REQ],
           datediff(MINUTE, t.PayDate,
                 CASE t.Status
                    WHEN 3 THEN GETDATE()
                    WHEN 4 THEN t.KeyRoomDate
                    When 5 THEN  t.KeyRoomDate
                    End) as KRRT,

                 datediff(MINUTE,t.PayDate,
                 CASE t.Status
                  WHEN 3 THEN GETDATE()
                  WHEN 4 THEN GETDATE()
                 WHEN 5 THEN t.DelDate
                 END) as DT

       FROM    
           dbo.Transaction_tbl t
       WHERE   

       ( 
           ([status] IN (3,4))
           OR 

           ([status]=5 and DelDate >=DATEADD(minute,-3,getdate()))
       )
       AND locid = @locid AND dtime >= @TodayMinus7Days
       ORDER BY  
           paydate 
    end
```

In Transaction_tbl i have a Index on locid,and status and dtime..and i want  taking only last 7 days data from my table..but this stored procedure scanning my entire table..
my execution plan is like this:
[image]

Comment: To prevent a full table scan, you'll need a [SARGABLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) query at the very least - in this case I *suspect* it is that `dtime` is not in a appropriate index, although even something such as outdated statistics can make SQL Server choose "ill-suited" plans.

Comment: how i can in co-operate SARGABLE with my stored procedure?

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with the SP, excepting perhaps cached plans. The query should run just the same - e.g. slow - normally in SSMS.

Comment: then? how i can achieve that?

Comment: Two things 1) just do a quick heck to make sure `dtime` is indexed, adding the index as needed 2) view the query plan in SSMS

Comment: i already created index on locid,status,,if i create index on dtime that will make my system slow right?

Comment: with query execution plan how i can understand increased performance ??

Comment: *sigh* Indexes trade off maintenance (storage and update cost) for faster queries, should they be properly used. Adding a *monotonically increasing* index is usually "fine", as it the fragmentation is effectively non-existent.

Comment: Once you *have* a query plan, add it to the question/post. Even if there are indexes, SQL Server may opt to ignore them if the query planner decides that a FTS is "better" (but look at the actual query plan first!).

Comment: Looks like most of the time is simply on sorting the result.. which means it is likely `paydate` is not participating in a suitable index.

Comment: so what i have to do now?

Comment: Create an index on `paydate` (such that it can use this index to sort the result). Also, consider changing the `dtime` index to include the `status` so the index is `(dtime, status)`.

Comment: i created index like this:CREATE INDEX IX_TRANSACTION ON transaction_tbl
(
    Locid ASC, DTime ASC, Status ASC
    )

Comment: Sure, that should work .. and also one on `paydate` for the ordering.

Comment: sir if i create index on this much variable..i am afraid about my insertion and updation...

Comment: Do you *have* a problem with insert/updates? Because right now there *is* a problem with the ORDER BY in the query ..

Comment: this i am doing test enviornment..if i implemented on live database...that will affect inserts and updates rignt,,in each minute around 30 records inserting to this table?

Comment: i havnt implemented this to live enviornemnt..i want to confirm that..if i created index to this much varibale that will affect to my insertion and updation

Comment: It might, it might not. It depends on many factors including the acceptable tolerances which will vary by environment - however, SQL Server is *good* and many index "problems" are really just related to lack of proper maintenance schedules.

Comment: sir..so what is the final decision i have to take regarding this stored procedure,,please

Comment: If it were me, *I* would add the index - because slow queries bug me.

Comment: ok,,sir,,so now i have to add index on paydate also?

Comment: If you want an index to be used in the ORDER BY, yes (also check out the details of the sort in the query plan to make sure that is the reason).

Comment: ok,,sir i will do..thanks for information